# Conditional aggregation across columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I have created a Pandas DataFrame in python that consists of various numerical amounts columns that are each paired with a separate alphabetical property column. I am trying to aggregate the numbers based on the property and save it as a new dataframe column.

i.e. for each row, sum column N if column N+1 has value "C".

I looked at various blogs and groupby, but I do not think they will work. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
Date  Amount1 Property1 Amount2 Property2 Amount3 Property3  TOTAL"C" TOTAL"N"
0      40        C        45       N        30       C         ???      ???
1      20        C        40       C        30       C         ???      ???    
2      60        N        80       N        30       C         ???      ???
3      40        C        60       N        30       N         ???      ???
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's effectively a sum across the row (`axis=1`) using a truth array and a values array.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Date  Amount1 Property1 Amount2 Property2 Amount3 Property3  TOTAL"C" TOTAL"N"
0      40        C        45       N        30       C         ???      ???
1      20        C        40       C        30       C         ???      ???    
2      60        N        80       N        30       C         ???      ???
3      40        C        60       N        30       N         ???      ???"""), sep="\s+")

# build list of column groups
props=[c for c in df.columns if "Property" in c]
amts=[c for c in df.columns if "Amount" in c]
# use fact False==0 to multiply values to the sum
df["TOTAL\"C\""] = (df[amts].values*(df[props]=="C").values).sum(axis=1)
df["TOTAL\"N\""] = (df[amts].values*(df[props]=="N").values).sum(axis=1)

df
```

### output

```
 Date  Amount1 Property1  Amount2 Property2  Amount3 Property3  TOTAL"C"  TOTAL"N"
    0       40         C       45         N       30         C        70        45
    1       20         C       40         C       30         C        90         0
    2       60         N       80         N       30         C        30       140
    3       40         C       60         N       30         N        40        90
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works really well nad is simple and quick. You are a  true legend.

Comment: Sorry for being dim, how do I accept the answer?

Comment: You will see a tick next to answer,  click on that.  Similar to if you see an answer to another question you see you can upvote it.  Good to recognise people that provide help on SO